# Accurate pan and zoom to svg node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, matrix, position

I am trying to pan and zoom to a svg node using d3js. But I cannot get my head around the math here.

If I force the desired zoom level to be 1, then I seem to get it right.
Here's an example:

```
let svg = d3.select('svg'),
    svgW = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
    svgH = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height,
    svgCentroid = {
        x : svgW / 2, 
        y : svgH / 2
    };

// zoom functionality has been applied to this one
let selector = d3.select('#container');

let elem = d3.select('[id="6"]'),
    elemBounds = elem.node().getBBox(),
    elemCentroid = {
        x : elemBounds.x + (elemBounds.width / 2), 
        y : elemBounds.y + (elemBounds.height / 2)
    };

let position = {
        x : svgCentroid.x - elemCentroid.x, 
        y : svgCentroid.y - elemCentroid.y
    };

selector.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(position.x, position.y)
            // set scale to 1
            .scale(1)
        );
```

My first naive thought was "piece of cake". I will just multiply the calculated positions with desired zoom level.  But, surprise surprise, that got me terribly wrong.

```
// failed miserably
selector.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
            .translate(position.x * 5, position.y * 5)
            .scale(5)
        );
```

I've been trying to play around with this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/smithant/664d6cf86e53442d09687b154a9a411d

It pretty much sums up my intentions, but even though it's right there I don't fully understand it and thus it does not work properly with the rest of my code. I guess what confuses me most about this particular example are how the variables have their names declared.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction here. How can I achieve this? What is the appropriate math to correctly zoom and pan within an SVG?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at the example you give. Use the JS function `to_bounding_box` but read the comment in the coffeescript. And all runs smooth. A minor error is the use of the `margin` argument in the function.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for what you have already? I don't understand your requirement. You have given an example which works well and says it doesn't work with your code. But I don't see you have used what's given in the example. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is:

```
function () {
    var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")),
        x = t.translate[0],
        y = t.translate[1];

    var scale = 10;

    svg.transition().duration(3000)
        .call(zoom.translate([((x * -scale) + (svgWidth / 2)), ((y * -scale) + svgHeight / 2)])
        .scale(scale).event);
}
```

Where this represents the element. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1gyjd2xt/109/) for a working example. In the example you'll be able to zoom to element after pressing on it. Also if panning and zooming an svg is all you need to do check out [this](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) library. It just works, no maths required :).